# ASP.NET Convert Class to 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbSqlQuery<Project.Models.HomesClass>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and I have a class called HomesClass and I this line in my edit method:

```
HomesClass homesClass = db.Data.Find(id);
```

so I tried to do another line like this

```
HomesClass homesClass = db.Data.SqlQuery("SELECT ....");
```

But then I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbSqlQuery<Project.Models.HomesClass>' to ‘Project.Models.HomesClass'
```

My question is how to do I convert this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code fails because `db.Data.SqlQuery("SELECT ....")` translates to an instance of type `DbSqlQuery`, which has no relation to your type `HomesClass`.
An instance of `DbSqlQuery` is just an object holding your query, not the result of executing it.
You need to execute the query so that it translates the results to an object that actually holds the data you are after.  You execute the query by calling methods on the DbSqlQuery instance that asks it to execute the query.

You are missing `FirstOrDefaultAsync`.

`HomesClass homesClass = await db.Data.SqlQuery("SELECT ....").FirstOrDefaultAsync();`

If you want a list:

`List<HomesClass> result = await db.Data.SqlQuery("SELECT ....").ToListAsync();`

Comment: But wouldnt this get only the first row?

Comment: Your code shows that you want only one object. If you want more than one you have to expect a list.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert one type to another type.

Following options can be used:

1. Implicit/Explicit Conversion Operator.
2. Writing an extension method to convert OneType to another.
3. Use third party library like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)